# How to select the first flight today in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database table with 3 columns (`flightID`, `Depday`, `Deptime`)

I need to select the first flight of today

I already got

```
SELECT * 
FROM flightdep
WHERE depday = dayofweek(CURDATE());
```

so now I get list with all the flights today but now I need to select the first one of the day

Comment: just simple `order by`....your query

Answer (score 1):

With Limit like this:

```
SELECT * FROM flightdep 
where depday = dayofweek(CURDATE())
ORDER BY depday,deptime DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably this is what you are looking for:

```
SELECT * FROM flightdep
  WHERE depday = dayofweek(CURDATE())
  ORDER BY deptime DESC LIMIT 1;
```

So you sort the result set by departure time (descending) and then limit the size of the result set to 1, thus only returning a single flight.

Not sure if dayofweek(CURDATE()) is what you are looking for though... Wouldn't it make more sense to check for todays date?